# PHP Array only stores last value

Tags: php, arrays

Well, basically what this code does is grab some links from a source code of a website and send them to an mp3 player. 
The big problem is on the get_link function, where i want to store the urls to an array. The section where im having problems is commented. 
Sorry for posting all this code but the functions are connected to each others.

```
function getHost($db,$id){
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){

            $sql1 = "SELECT host FROM mixtape WHERE id=?";
            $stm = $db->prepare($sql1);
            $stm->execute(array($id));
            $row1 = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row1['host']=='host1'){

                $sql2 = "SELECT link1 FROM faixa WHERE id_mixtape IN(SELECT id FROM mixtape WHERE id=?)";
                $stm = $db->prepare($sql2);
                $stm->execute(array($id));

                $rows_affected = $stm->rowCount();
                        $array=array();
                if (count($rows_affected) > 0) {
                    for($i=1; $i <= $rows_affected; $i++) {

                        $row2 = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $url=$row2['link1'];

                        get_Link($db,$url,$i,$rows_affected,$array);                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function get_Link($db,$url,$pos,$rows_affect,$array){ 

        $find = 'url:';
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = explode("\n", $data);

        for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++) {
            if (strpos($data[$line], $find) !== false) {
                $link = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,"", $data[$line]);
                $v[]=$link;
            }   
        }

        if($pos!=$rows_affect-1){
            $url="mylink.com/".$link."|";
        }else{
            $url="mylink.com/".$link."&amp";
        }

        $array[$pos]=$url;  
        var_dump($array); // Here says that are 3 values in the array. True

        if($pos==$rows_affect-1){
            var_dump($array); // Here is only showing the last value in the array. Why?
            player($db,$array);
        }
    }

    function player($db,$array){
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            foreach($array as $i=>$item){ 
                echo $item; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The simple reason for this is that you have your array being defined inside a foreach, while, for..etc loop which will constantly overwrite it, move the array outside the loop

Comment: declare your $array = array();

Comment: @DarylGill Could you be more specific? Im kinda noob on arrays. Isnt my array outside of the for on get_Link function?

Comment: $row2 is inside the loop, so the variable scope is the for, when you go outside the for the memory is cleaned.
You need to do (Before the for, if) => $row2=array().
So everything inside or bellow it in the scope can access the $row2

Comment: declare your array before $sql1 for example and add a param array to your get_link function

Comment: @miguelfsf, it is outside the get_Link, but when the next loop occurs the variable is recreated, so the values inside it are cleaned

Comment: @demonofnight i have put $row2=array(); before the if and for on getHost function as you said and still the same. Im trying to figure out this for two days and cant find the problem -.-

Comment: @Nagasaki I updated the code. Is that correct?

Comment: @miguelfsf Yes it is ;)

Comment: @Nagasaki But still the same. Im going insanse with this :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miguelfsf, you must first learn about variable scope.

Your problem is, you created the $array=array() (the $array show be the $row2).
You declared a new variable, but you didn't used, the $array was just to tell you, declare your array that way

```
$row2=array().
```

After that you need to do

```
$row2[] = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Why?
Because the assoc returns a associative array, then it will do
$array => {title => "last title} = $newData => {title => "new title"}
It will replace the value
Using the [] everytime you do this it'll create a new element.
Then

```
{
   0 => { title => "title1"}
   1 => { title => "title2"}
   2 => { title => "title3"}
   3 => { title => "title4"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
$c=0;

    for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++) {
        if (strpos($data[$line], $find) !== false) {
            $link = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,"", $data[$line]);
            $v[$c]=$link;
        }   
    }
```

Should be like:

```
 $c=0;

    for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++) {
        if (strpos($data[$line], $find) !== false) {
            $link = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,"", $data[$line]);
            $v[$c]=$link;
            $c = $c+1; //this is missing or $c++;
        }   
    }
```

OR:

```
    for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++) {
        if (strpos($data[$line], $find) !== false) {
            $link = preg_replace($reg_exUrl,"", $data[$line]);
            $v[]=$link; //That way works too
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Tried both ways and still printing only the last value of the array. Thanks for the help anyway